помогите с заданием python!
Необходимо написать программу, которая будет считывать со стандартного ввода строку и выводить уникальные символы, встретившиеся в этой строке, в лексикографическом порядке по возрастанию. Символы из входа нужно приводить к нижнему регистру. Символ пробела не нужно учитывать при формировании результата. Выходные символы нужно разделять пробелом.
вот задание, Я попробовал сделать так
def unique_chars_lexicographically(s):
s = s.lower()
unique_chars = {char for char in s if char != ' '} 
sorted_unique_chars = sorted(unique_chars)
return ' '.join(sorted_unique_chars) 
input_string = input() 
print(unique_chars_lexicographically(input_string))

выдает ошибку

Какую ошибку? А если отступы сделать, как в Python положено?

tio.run
print(" ".join(sorted(set(input().lower())-{" "})))

tio.run
print(*sorted(set(input().lower())-{" "}))


@u111, исправил)

@StanislavVolodarskiy, да, можно)))

Это можно сделать так:
def unique_chars(s):
    s = s.replace(' ', '').lower() # Убираем пробелы и приводим к нижнему регистру
    lst = list(set(s)) # Только уникальные символы
    sorted_lst = sorted(lst) # Сортируем список
    return ' '.join(sorted_lst) # Разделяем символы пробелами
string = 'abcbabbbabababc12acbba'
print(unique_chars(string))


В целом работает но я забыл добавить чтобы он выводил символы именно так Входные данные
abcabcaaabb12bbbaaa
Выходные данные
1 2 a b c

Ну так и есть..
